# mongoimport : 'error validating settings: only one positional argument is allowed'

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

Ok so I am trying.... to Importing a dummy JSON file into MongoDB and getting this error, a Google search yields no definitive explanation, and though this topic is [already on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953611/mongodb-error-validating-settings-only-one-positional-argument-is-allowed), that's more a syntax related error.

I think my syntax is ok, however if it is not please point it out and let me know. Also I think the other issue is my path [format correct] ? or is it something entirely different I am missing.

I don't understand the error and thus can't find a suitable "plain English" explanation anywhere to figure it out myself, so if you have a link please drop it in for me, it will be appreciated....

*The error:*

```
$ mongoimport --jsonArray --collection bank_data /Macintosh HD/Users/Tinus/Downloads/bank_data.json/bank_data.json
2016-09-20T13:23:56.592+1200    error validating settings: only one positional argument is allowed
```

---

-: Running OSX 
-: Mongod started
-: Using /data/db path and connected to test "All good"
-: running mongoimport from separate shell

---

```
$ mongo --version MongoDB shell version: 3.2.8

$ mongoimport --jsonArray --collection some_data --file /path/path/data.json
$ mongoimport --jsonArray --collection some_data /path/path/data.json
```

A) Also when adding --file i get: incompatible options: --file and positional argument(s)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try it like that by quoting your path

```
$ mongoimport --jsonArray --collection bank_data '/Macintosh HD/Users/Tinus/Downloads/bank_data.json/bank_data.json'
```

The error

```
error validating settings: only one positional argument is allowed
```

comes from the fact that your path contains a space which results in splitting it into two separate arguments (if not guarded by surrounding quotes)

---

BTW: Are your sure your path ends with `'...bank_data.json/bank_data.json'` and not just one `'bank_data.json'`?

Comment: Thanks so much mate! Will give it a go and let you know. I

Comment: Mine was a different import scenario. I was using data types and trying to specify date format like date_ms\(yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss\) [as shown in mongoimport docs]. got this same error and when quoted such as date_ms\('yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss'\), the error's gone and import worked!

Answer (score 3):

~Fix~

A) I changed the path to reed direct from a new folder on root
B) For any other’s having the same issue on mac osx —leave out the base root in your path , in my example above it was [ Macintosh HD] 
the import works without specifying it. thus it was changed to ..

```
        $ mongoimport --jsonArray --collection bank_data '/Users/Tinus/Downloads/bank_data.json/bank_data.json'
```

C) Yes the quotes are essential and was also added…
D) Remember not to run it inside the mongo shell.

*thumbs Up again to DAXaholic*

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same error and the reason was my mistake of specifying options. Instead of --collection or -c, I had -collection. Below is what worked for me.

mongoimport --db ShardTestDB --collection Test --host : --jsonArray --file "<path_to_json>/Substations_new.json"

Make sure that the file is included inside quotes.

Answer (score 0):

even i faced same issue while importing tsv file to db including --headerline to the command line solved the issue.please find entire import command used to successfully import tsv file

mongoimport --host Cluster0-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-00-qvmvm.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-qvmvm.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-qvmvm.mongodb.net:27017 --ssl --username learning --password --authenticationDatabase admin --db node_deploy --collection node_deploy --type tsv --file games.tsv --headerline
[Note]
above command is to import a database in tsv format to mongodb hosted in AWS using mongodb.com

Answer (score 0):

Above solutions did not work for me on Windows 10.  I figured out solution as follows:

```
mongoimport --jsonArray --db=db_name --collection=collection_name --file=file_name.json
```

Which resulted in:

```
2019-12-29T02:26:50.041-0700    connected to: mongodb://localhost/
2019-12-29T02:26:50.088-0700    2411 document(s) imported successfully. 0 document(s) failed to import.
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
mongoimport --host 172.18.60.1 --port 50000 --db MYDB --collection BUSINESS_FILE --file "/opt/data/JSON/BUSINESS_FILE.json"
```

P.S. My port is not default port of MongoDB so make sure you put your mongos port there instead of 50000 which is mine.